# Are FF add-ons visible through Tor?

Tags: firefox, add-on

I ask because that would be a bad info leak and could be used to identify someone uniquely instead of just a Tor user in a sea of Tor users.

On that note, can I spoof them or hide them if the answer is yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spoof them, yes. And - there's no problem in detecting add-ons in the Firefox bundled in TBB. It's a regular case, and if you're using TBB instance of FF it's more than detectable, actually. It's because of the fact, that it LTS-like version, not an ordinary FF. It states lower version, but due to the fact, that many patches were backported to it in it's development cycle, it does not have some bugs usual for an old version it states. So - it's pretty clear that you're using TBB FF, elaborating some JS tests, for example.

Comment: Such a detailed reply! Although, how would I go about spoofing them in FF, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @KrimsonKaiser You can, and - actually - I'd rather recommend you a more interesting technique : use an isolated VM with FF + modified versions of add-ons. Make a start snapshot with them installed and an emptu cache e.t.c.[keep VM out of routing, so it would not be able to reach an outer internet], after a usage - restore that VM to it's original[clean] state, randomize/fake-another-value some parameters and use it again =) It promises much more fun =)

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to just use the plain Tor Browser and not install future Add-ons.

How visible an add-on is greatly depends on the add-on itself. If it blocks ads then one will be able to see that you don't load ads, if it "phones home" then the IP might be the one from Tor (or not), but it still might create some kind of ID that is unique to you.

I'd suggest not to use any Add-ons other than the ones installed on the Tor Browser per default. I don't think it really is possible to completely prevent any potential information leak of any Add-on out there.

Comment: @KrimsonKaiser Happy I could help. Please choose an answer that you think answers your question best (can be done where you up- and downvote, left of the message. This way your question is considered answered by Stack Exchange and will help people having a similar or the same question.